fbchat fails when trying to log in
I'm trying to make a simple chatbot as a beginner project using fbchat but I cannot get it to work.
On Facebook, I am getting notifications of successful logins to my account, but fbchat is failing. I have logged in from my computer browser to the Facebook account I am using with the same IP address, so Facebook should not be blocking my login attempts.
Python code:
from fbchat import Client

email = 'email'
password = 'password'

client = Client(email, password)

if client.isLoggedIn():
    print("Logged in successfully!")
else:
    print("Login failed!")

Console printout:
Attempt #1 failed, retrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fbchat/_client.py", line 205, in login
    self._state = State.login(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fbchat/_state.py", line 151, in login
    return cls.from_session(session=session)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fbchat/_state.py", line 190, in from_session
    revision = int(r.text.split('"client_revision":', 1)[1].split(",", 1)[0])
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

It keeps trying for 3 more attempts with the same results.
